# SQL converting Text fields

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, casting

I'm bumping into some`null` fields in a SQL2005 db.

Some report `Null` and others have values like `1.00` or `713.00`.
I'd like a bullet proof way to convert the 'Null's to 0 and the '1.00' and '713.00' values into `Money` types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Text_Convert
(
     my_string     TEXT     NULL
)
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Text_Convert VALUES (NULL)
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Text_Convert VALUES ('7.10')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Text_Convert VALUES ('xxx')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Text_Convert VALUES ('$20.20')
INSERT INTO dbo.Test_Text_Convert VALUES ('20.2020')
GO

SELECT
     CASE
          WHEN ISNUMERIC(CAST(my_string AS VARCHAR(MAX))) = 1
               THEN CAST(ISNULL(CAST(my_string AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '0') AS MONEY)
          ELSE 0
     END
FROM
    dbo.Test_Text_Convert
GO
```

I've set invalid strings to be 0, but you could easily change that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert from `null` via the `coalesce` function:

```
coalesce(a, b) //returns b if a is null, a otherwise
```

Answer (score 1):

To cast from text to money and handle nulls, try this:

```
CAST(COALESCE(column, '0') AS MONEY)
```

See [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349(SQL.90).aspx) and [`CAST`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928(SQL.90).aspx) for details.

An alternative when things are more complex is [`CASE`..`WHEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765(SQL.90).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the performance will be like, but 2005 introduced the `varchar(MAX)` and `nvarchar(MAX)` data types (among others like `varbinary(MAX)`. These are true varchars and nvarchars, and can be used in any place where they could (like Convert), but also have the capacity of `Text` and `Image` fields. In fact, the `Text` and `Image` types are actually deprecated, so going forward it's recommended that you use the new types.

That being said, you could just use this:

```
convert(Money, coalesce(text_column_name, 0))
```